# Is there a way to determine the size of BLAS IDAMAX function?

Tags: integer, blas

I would like to determine the size of integer function IDAMAX in any BLAS Fortran library. It can be either 4-bytes (i32lp64 model) or 8-bytes (ilp64).

Knowing this size can determine what overall integer declaration (integer*4 or integer*8) is in a prebuild BLAS library.

The problem is that sizeof(*idamax_(&n, dx,&incx)) of the program below is always returning 4, though I would expect 8 with MKL-integer*8 blas.

Any comments, please ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
extern * idamax_(); // external Fortran BLAS function IDAMAX
int n=2; int incx=1;
//long  n=2; long incx=1;
double dx[2]; dx[0]=1.0; dx[1]=2.0;
printf("sizeof(n)=%i\n",sizeof(n));
printf("sizeof(*idamax_(&n, dx, &incx))=%i\n",sizeof(*idamax_(&n, dx,&incx)) ); // still returns four !!!
//printf("sizeof(idamax_(&n, dx, &incx))=%i\n",sizeof(idamax_(&n, dx, &incx)) );
// idamax call sometimes crashes with wrong integer sizes - with MKL, but with GNU ibblas.a ! The same with Fortran
idamax_(&n, dx, &incx);
}
```

Comment: How do you compile and link your code for the 'MKL-integer*8 blas' case?

Comment: Hi Eric, for MKL-i8: icc -g sizeof_idamax.c -Wl,--start-group /cvmfs/it.gsi.de/compiler/intel/15.0/composer_xe_2015.2.164/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_lapack95_ilp64.a -lmkl_intel_ilp64 -openmp -Wl,--end-group -Wl,--start-group -lmkl_intel_ilp64 -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_core -lpthread /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so -openmp -Wl,--end-group   ; on the Intel web-page there formulaire to get proper MKL linking flags.

Comment: It seems, that the default of 
extern * idamax_(); // external Fortran BLAS function IDAMAX
is always int (integer*4), although I did not declare it.

I though that the "sizeof(idamax_(&n, dx,>> &incx)) );" is determined on the runtime, depending on the  integer*4/8 model of the linked blas library.

Comment: sizeof(...) is determined on the compile time, depending only on the declaration of the function return type, which you did not specified and was given the default type of `int`. Without the last line of your code, you don't even need to link to MKL.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not determining any function in any BLAS Fortran library. It's determining a function declared by yourself with

```
extern * idamax_();
```

As you did not specify the return type of this function, it's default to `int`, with a constant size of 4 on most machines.

If you want determine the return type of MKL's BLAS function, the only thing you need to do is to check the header file. In `${MKL_ROOT}/include/mkl_blas.h` you can find

```
MKL_INT IDAMAX(const MKL_INT *n, const double *x, const MKL_INT *incx);
```

The return type is `MKL_INT`, and the size is `sizeof(MKL_INT)`, which is determined on compile time. You can find something similar like this in `${MKL_ROOT}/include/mkl_types.h`

```
#ifdef MKL_ILP64
  #ifndef MKL_INT
    #define MKL_INT MKL_INT64
  #endif
#else
  #ifndef MKL_INT
    #define MKL_INT int
  #endif
#endif
```

So the size of `MKL_INT` depends only on whether you define `MKL_ILP64` or not at the compile time.

Comment: Thanks for the anwer,Eric, so the MKL library has well defined interface with respect to the integer-size. But how about the GNU blas library, libblas.a ? In this case, when I call integer*4 idamax with integer*8 parameters n,incx, there is no crash as with the analogous MKL-blas, and idamax gives good result. Would be good to detect the integer-"status" of any blas library through small testing program.

Comment: @MiroIliaš the key point is you shall find the official header file of GNU blas lib and check how it declare the APIs. No crash probably means luck or the comipler automatically cast int64 to int32 for you before calling the function.

Comment: Hi, this Fortran API is simple integer returning function, "integer function idamax(n,dx,incx)" (part of blas). I hoped to distinguish 4/8-bytes of the returning integer, but  it is always returning size 4 - the default int.

Comment: Not a fortran expert, but you may check the input dimension type of say, `gemm()`, which may be more robust to determine IP64/ILP64. At least MKL CBLAS API `cblas_idamax()` always return int64 in both modes.